# How to make a div autofill empty space in html page

Tags: html, css

I have written a html page where i want a header,content,footer. All these three portions are enclosed in divs and it looks as below

But i observe that the header div  does not occupy the full space which was provided(ie.,height: 50% in  CSS)

and the content div (containing table) does not occupy the space available between header and footer divs though a height of 100% is spaecified in CSS

The html written is as follows.Am i missing something .

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Html with divs</title>
<style type="text/css">

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    font-size:100%;
    font-weight:normal;
}
q:before,q:after{
    content:'';
}
abbr,acronym{
    border:0;
}

html{
    height:100%;

}
body{
    font-family:Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size:0.75em;
    color:#333;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0px;
}


#header1
{
    background-color: steelblue;
    height: 50%;
}


h1{
    font-family:Calibri, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:2em;
    width:520px;
}


#content
{
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 5px;
height:100%;

}

#content table
{
width:100%;
}



#footer {
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
        height:70px;
        }
#footer div#navigation {
    background: steelblue;
        height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
}

#footer div#navigation div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#footer div#navigation div p {
    color: #995870;

        color:white;
        width:100%;
        align:center;
        font-size: 11px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>


    <div id="header1">
        <p align="center">Header1</p>
        <p align="center">Header2</p>
        <p align="center">Header3</p>

    </div>

    <div id="content">

                <table bgcolor="#fadd09" align="center" style="color:white">
                    <tr><td>Text1 here</td><td>  <input type="text" name="value1"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Text2 here</td><td>  <input type="text" name="value2"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Text3 here</td><td>  <input type="text" name="value3"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Text4 here</td><td>  <input type="text" name="value4"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Text5 here</td><td>  <input type="text" name="value5"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Text6 here</td><td>  <input type="text" name="value6"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Text7 here</td><td>  <input type="text" name="value7"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Text8 here</td><td>  <input type="text" name="value8"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Text9 here</td><td>  <input type="text" name="value9"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Text10 here</td><td>  <input type="text" name="value10"/></td></tr>

                </table>


    </div>

            <!--Footer-->
        <div id="footer">
            <div id="navigation">
                <p style="color: ivory;font-size: 15px;">footer-head</p>
                <div style="float: inherit">
                    <p>The footer</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you should give 100% height to the Body tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting height to 100% on the html and body to will allow you to specify a percentage height on the divs, but there are still a number of problems with your page. I've created a simpler example based on your code.

Explanation:

- I added a doctype at the top of the page, so that you get a more consistent result between browsers. I've added the transitional doctype.
- Each region is surrounded by a 'container' div, which is where the height is specified. The headercontainer is set to 50%, contentcontainer set to 40%, and the footer to 10%. In your code, you had the footer absolutely positioned at the bottom of the page. This seems to work fine, but it was actually chopping/overlapping the bottom of the content div.
- The container divs all have overflow: auto; set, so that if the page is resized, scrollbars will appear in each section if the content is too long (test it out).
- The inner divs, 'header', 'content' and 'footer' should contain any page content, so that margins/paddings that occur on elements like p, h1, or anything else for that matter won't cause your page to become larger than 100% - In your page, you had a 'p' element directly within the header1 div, which was causing a white bar to appear at the top of your page (due to the 10px margin at the top of the p element by default).

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Html with divs</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * 
        {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        html
        {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body
        {
            font-family: Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.3em;
            color: #333;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0px;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #headercontainer
        {
            background-color: steelblue;
            overflow: auto;
            height: 50%;
        }

        #header
        {
            padding: 10px;
        }

        #contentcontainer
        {
            background-color: orange;
            overflow: auto;
            height: 40%;
        }

        #content
        {
            padding: 10px;
        }

        #footercontainer
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 10%;
            background: steelblue;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        #footer
        {
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="headercontainer">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>
                Header</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contentcontainer">
        <div id="header">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
            euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad
            minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip
            ex ea commodo consequat.<br />
            Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat,
            vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio
            dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait
            nulla facilisi.
            <br />
            Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming
            id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est
            usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt
            lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus,
            qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum.<br />
            Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit
            litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem
            modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footercontainer">
        <div id="footer">
            <h1>
                Footer</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this, change:

```
#content{
background-color: orange;
padding: 5px;
height:50%;
}
```

By using over 100% in total you are making the page extra large. Let me know if that is what you are thinking. Also I would recommend changing the footer to percentage based height too if you are using % for the rest of the divs.

You want to have the total height= 100%

so the height of header+content+footer=100%, for example, 40%+50%+10%=100%